# Cannot install nginx from source

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, make

I'm trying to install `nginx 1.13.1` from source on `Ubuntu 16.04`. My configure command is the following:

```
./configure --with-cc-opt='-g -O2 -fPIE -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2' --with-ld-opt='-Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -fPIE -pie -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now' --prefix=/usr/share/nginx --conf-path=/etc/nginx/nginx.conf --http-log-path=/var/log/nginx/access.log --error-log-path=/var/log/nginx/error.log --lock-path=/var/lock/nginx.lock --pid-path=/run/nginx.pid --http-client-body-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/body --http-fastcgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/fastcgi --http-proxy-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/proxy --http-scgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/scgi --http-uwsgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/uwsgi --with-debug --with-pcre-jit --with-ipv6 --with-http_ssl_module --with-http_stub_status_module --with-http_realip_module --with-http_auth_request_module --with-http_addition_module --with-http_dav_module --with-http_geoip_module --with-http_gunzip_module --with-http_gzip_static_module --with-http_v2_module --with-http_sub_module --with-http_xslt_module --with-stream --with-stream_ssl_module --with-mail --with-mail_ssl_module --with-threads --with-http_realip_module
```

The configure command work fine. But when I'm trying to compile it using `make`, it shows `make[1]: Leaving directory '/root/nginx/nginx-1.13.1'`and exit after some compilation messages. The binaries aren't updated.

The log of all commands: https://hastebin.com/sohuwivuto.pl

I ran the following commands:

```
(The configure plugin)
make
make install
```

Comment: Your question is near impossible to answer without an actual log of the compile and the commands you've ran. The answer below is probably correct, in the sense that you didn't run "make install" by the looks of it. Running "make" only compiles it.

Comment: Added it @AlexanderK

Comment: Which binaries did you check? Your --prefix is /usr/share/nginx which I doubt is in your PATH, thus if the binary you are checking is another place that explains why it's not updated.

The compiled binary is in `/usr/share/nginx/sbin/nginx`

Comment: @AlexanderK I copied the arguments from the installation I had before, so I thought it's correct. My current binary is in `/usr/sbin/nginx`. But there's also a binary in the path you wrote and it seems to be the correct binary. What do I have to change in the configure command to install the binary into the correct path?

Comment: Added an answer for you! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shameless answer for points.

The binary is located in the wrong location due to having:

1. The PATH set to /usr/share/nginx
2. Not set --sbin-path=/usr/sbin/nginx

Fix your ./configure arguments as needed. If you write `./configure --help` you will be presented with arguments available. If unsure about any of them, consult documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at my [Nginx tutorial](https://www.photographerstechsupport.com/tutorials/hosting-wordpress-on-aws-tutorial-part-2-setting-up-aws-for-wordpress-with-rds-nginx-hhvm-php-ssmtp/#nginx-source), that includes how to build it.

They key parts for you are the two make lines, particular "make install". The configure line may not be right for you.

```
./configure --prefix=/etc/nginx --sbin-path=/usr/sbin/nginx --conf-path=/etc/nginx/nginx.conf --error-log-path=/var/log/nginx/error.log --http-log-path=/var/log/nginx/access.log --pid-path=/var/run/nginx.pid --lock-path=/var/run/nginx.lock --http-client-body-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/client_temp --http-proxy-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/proxy_temp --http-fastcgi-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/fastcgi_temp --http-uwsgi-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/uwsgi_temp --http-scgi-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/scgi_temp --user=nginx --group=nginx --with-http_ssl_module --with-http_realip_module --with-http_gunzip_module --with-http_gzip_static_module --with-threads --with-file-aio --with-http_v2_module --with-cc-opt='-O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=native' --add-module=../ngx_cache_purge-2.3 --add-module=../headers-more-nginx-module
make && make install
make clean  (NB: optional)
service nginx start
```

Comment: It already happen before the `make install`. I'll never execute it, because the `make` command already throws the error.

Comment: This is why you should include as much information as you can in your question. It would be difficult to help given there's no error message. It could even just be that the user building Nginx doesn't have permission to replace the current binary.

Comment: Also, be sure to stop your current running nginx before "make install" or it will fail

Comment: @Tim I added all informations I could find the to question.